# CRM 2011 How can i get the Default Queue of a user by using SOAP

Tags: queue, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I want to be able to retrieve the default queue of a user in dynamics crm 2011 using SOAP calls. I tried searching but did not generate any leads. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to query `queueid` field from `systemuser` entity.
Example:

```
     var userId = new Guid("BCF84567-DE3C-4470-9A61-4B9A32351CB6");
     var query = new QueryExpression("systemuser") { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "queueid" }) };
     query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.Equal, userId));
     var req = new RetrieveMultipleRequest()
                   {
                       Query = query
                   };
     var res = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)slos.Execute(req);
     var result = res.EntityCollection[0].Attributes["queueid"];
```

This will return entity reference to default user query.